# async/await in Breeze Controller

Tags: asynchronous, breeze

Am I correct in assuming that a **BreezeController does *not* support the async/await** feature in .Net 4.5?

Take for example:

```
public class BreezeController {

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<AssetType> AssetTypes()
    {
        return this.contextProvider.Context.AssetTypes;
    }
```

It makes no sense to change this to:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<AssetType>> AssetTypes()
    {
        return await this.contextProvider.Context.AssetTypes.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Doing so would now result in a Select * FROM AssetTypes when the client side breeze query may only be fetching a filtered list of AssetTypes

It seems that for breeze to support async on the server, BreezeQueryableAttribute and / or QueryHelper would need to perform the async/await.

Assuming I'm not off track, are there any plans in supporting async in a BreezeController?

Thanks
Christian

Comment: It's on our backlog. I have no timeframe for you. Please [vote for this on our UserVoice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5963097-breeze-web-api-components-should-support-async).

Answer (score 1):

The AsyncSave branch of this implements an asynchronous save for the EF context.  I am just looking at updating it to support latest version of breeze https://github.com/gilesbradshaw/breeze.server.net/tree/AsyncSave